# Should there be an option for asking and answering questions anonymously?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

As the questions on here are to do with problems parents are having while parenting their children, should there be an option for asking and answering questions anonymously?
Isn't it unfair to our children to detail their problems on a public website?

Answer (score 3):

You can already contribute anonymously, although it's so obvious that it's in fact invisible:

**Just log out.** You can ask and answer questions without being logged in. When you do that, you'll be posting as an anonymous user.

*Update:* We have to assume that users have a certain level of ability to think for themselves. Posting things on the public Internet (especially with the content's [open license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) is, well, *public,* and we're not tasked with teaching people how to post wisely.

IMHO, whatever the parents might post is nothing compared to the compromising stuff the kids themselves thoughtlessly post on Facebook et al.

Comment: While thats true it doesn't it make it harder for me to keep track of my questions? It also makes it harder to give an answer that mentions my personal experience where it may violate my families privacy, so I may not give the answer.

Comment: It would also be nice if you could earn reputation while still being able to post anonymous answers and questions, though I do realise that Anonymous-Reputation is an odd concept :) .

Comment: (1) when you post anonymously your computer gets a cookie. You can track your anon posts as long as you don't delete that cookie.  (2) No amount of technical anonymity can save you if you post your name... write deliberately.  (3) The only way to earn rep on anonymous posts is to merge them into a user account. They will then no longer be anonymous.

Comment: Here's a good example of a question that should have been asked anonymously: [link](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/explaining-to-a-toddler-when-masturbation-is-appropriate?newsletter=1&nlcode=16977|6400) "Explaining to a toddler when masturbation is appropriate"

Comment: @P.Turpie You may actually be imposing your own personal cultural values onto this situation. Perhaps the OP feels there is nothing to be embarrassed about, and is quite comfortable discussing such issues in an open and public setting?

Comment: It isn't a question of whether the poster is embarrassed about the topic, but whether their children's privacy should be protected. It is one thing to post about my own private information but another to post someone elses. In this regards the parenting site is probably unique in the stack exchange network we often aren't asking about ourselves but our children and issues that they may be embarrassed about.

Comment: @P.Turpie: I see your point. As I commented earlier, people must _"write deliberately,"_ not just on this site but in any public space. I don't see any reason for _this_ site to make special arrangements if people disclose personal information. However, if you see anything _grossly_ wrong (like actual abuse) then _please flag it_ for moderator attention.